# NuGet package doesn't copy file to destination project

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I create a NuGet package with all components that I need to reuse in some project. In the project with components I have some `.less` and `.js` files. I need to copy these files in `wwwroot` of my projects when I install my NuGet package. I tried with `contentFiles` and `files` tags but nothing works:

```
<contentFiles>
    <files include="**/wwwroot/**" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
</contentFiles>
```

Or with files:

```
<files> 
    <file src="contentFiles\**" target="contentFiles" /> 
    <file src="wwwroot\**" target="wwwroot" />
    <file src="**\wwwroot\**" target="wwwroot" /> 
</files>
```

There is some tries. Nothing works. Is possible to do what I want?

These files don't even appear in the final build. `.less` file must be copied in project because they have an `import` of a base file with constants which could change in different projects. `.js` files can also appear only in the compiled.

With NuGet Package Explorer I tried to create `contentFolder` similar to this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418304/5731129. I created subfolders and add an image, bbut after installation the file was not copied.