# Copy content files from Nuget package referenced by another Nuget package

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I want to get a file from a referenced Nuget package into my output folder. The packages are generated using Visual Studio 2017  on a .NET Standard project with the new csproj file format and 'GeneratePackageOnBuild' enabled.

For example, I have two Nuget packages (A and B) and package B depends on A. Package A includes a content file, like a config file. Next to these packages I have an application which includes package B. This application uses stuff from package A and B, and therefor needs the file from page A.

```
NugetPackageA
|- ClassA.cs
|- RequiredFile.txt

NugetPackageB
|-Dependencies
  |- Nuget
    |- NugetPackageA
|- ClassB.cs

Application
|-Dependencies
  |- Nuget
    |- NugetPackageB
|- Program.cs
```

What I did is enable the packing of the file in the project file (based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49438592/2471080)):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="RequiredFile.txt">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <PackagePath>contentFiles\any\any\;content\any\any\</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

If I open the Nuget package and nuspec file I see that the files are correctly packed and the properties seems to be ok:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>NugetPackageA</id>
    ...
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/RequiredFile.txt" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

When the Application directly depends on NugetPackageA the file is correctly added to the project and copied to the output directory.

So for now I see these workarounds;

1. Adding the Nuget reference directly
2. Make a script that tries to find the correct package and version in $(NuGetPackageFolders) and manually copy the files
3. Change NugetPackageB to also includes RequiredFile.txt

Does anybody else have a solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you consuming/installing the nugets? package.config or PackageReference?

Comment: I am using PackageReference to install them.

Comment: I will try writing a complete answer tomorrow, if no one else does. Meanwhile look up how to use packagename.targets, I am not sure if it can be used for csproj  packaging(it should). I think it might solve your issue. Package A should be responsible of copying needed files to the bin/obj folder of the project it is installed in, not package B.

Comment: I am also suspicious about the “file is added to project” part for package reference installs, I thought that is not the way it works (was not able to make it work)

Comment: @alexandru I am trying the packagename.targets, but it is not working yet. I will keep trying, but in the meanwhile I have created a test repo here: https://github.com/denxorz/NuGetReferenceTest

Related link I have found: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6743

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1aKaXycL Something like this worked for me (nuspec + targets)

Comment: One thing that I might be doing wrong, LibB has a `ProjectReference` to LibA. If I change this to a `PackageReference` then the file is visible in both LibB and the Application (even if I remove all the scripts and csproj changes and just set the file to `Content`). In LibB the 'Copy To Output Directory' is set correctly as well, but in the Application it is still 'Do Not Copy'.

Comment: I will take a look at the github project when I find the time